# Is there a way to have a column in SharePoint which has multiple links?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I currently have a normal SharePoint list with about 15 columns or so. I need one of the columns to have a list of links. I know SharePoint lets you have 1 link and it also lets you have multiple lines of text... So I thought it would be there as an option, but no such luck. Anyone knows a solution for this? I wasn't able to find any info online, which doesn't happen often. I guess I wasn't looking for the right keywords? If anyone can point me into the right direction, it would be great!

Thanks
-V

Comment: You might try posting your question on the similar website [SharepointOverflow](http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, I didn't know there was such a website.

Comment: Why not have a single link per column, then concatenate columns with a 3rd (or however many) calculated column?

Comment: Heh, my question is rather old *points at date* so I don't remember what I was trying to do at work then. Hopefully that'll help someone that might have a similar question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a multiplelines text field, and configured it to be Enhaced Rich Text enable. It would allow you to insert your links as in a HTML page (it would be the same as to use a CEWQ)

Answer (score 0):

We have a custom filed CALLed Document Link Field that enabled you to link multiple documents to a list item, maybe this is what yuo are looking for. In any case either you need a custom field, or use a multiple lines of text

[Infowise Document Link Field](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=DocumentLinkField)

Comment: I believe that the OP is asking about multiple hyperlinks in the same list item - can your custom field do that?

Comment: Yeah, Ryan, you understood correctly. I'll look into this, let you guys know if I succeed.

Comment: The field enables you to link one list item to multiple documents/pages. There is a screenshot on the product page